# Fetch value from session Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, session

I'm using a link and send some of the parameter with them,

```
%a{:href => "/auth/#{key}?profile_id=#{@user.id}&profile_type=user}
```

These parameter goes in session and after that save in db.
Before saving in the db, I want to fetch value of these parameter ,for this I use in my application controller:

```
before_filter :social_media_type

 def social_media_type
   Rails.logger.debug"***********Session Set*****#{params[:profile_id]}*********#{params[:profile_type]}***"
   if params[:profile_type].present? and params[:profile_id].present?      
    session[:social_profile_type] = params[:profile_type]
    session[:social_profile_id] = params[:profile_id]
   end
end
```

But here is a problem, It does not fetch any value when I check it in logger.
Is it not correct or have any error? please give your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that your HAML is even parsing. You are missing a closing quote (unless its a typo)

```
%a{:href => "/auth/#{key}?profile_id=#{@user.id}&profile_type=user"} Hello
```

Personally I would always prefer a helper tag, because its easier to make changes, like:

```
= link_to "Hello", auth_path(:key => key, :profile_id => @user.id, :profile_type => "user"
```

With a route in routes.rb like

```
match 'auth/:key' => "your_controller#action", :as => :auth
```

Comment: Hey @Bornfree thanks for your response.Both are same, the anchor tag also takes the value of `profile_type` and `profile_id` but I'm not able to get those value form session as I created a filter .

Comment: Oh. So you're saying the session variables are empty but params variable is getting populated? I got confused because you said the logger was empty.

Comment: when I hover over the link it has value, after click it goes in `before_filter :social_media_type` where I check value in logger which is empty